# Name error. Can't assign variable to array

Tags: python, arrays

Within a readlines() loop, a part is presented below which shows error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 56, in <module>
    print("%s,%s are {:5.16f}, {:5.16f}"%(atom2,atom3)).format(Nj,Nk)
NameError: name 'Nj' is not defined
```

```
            if i>7:
                    dummy=line.strip().split()
                    j=i-7
                    Njx=dummy[0]
                    Njy=dummy[1]
                    Njz=dummy[2]

                    import string
                    if j==2:
                      Njx=string.atof(Njx)
                      Njy=string.atof(Njy)
                      Njz=string.atof(Njz)
                      Nj = [Njx, Njy, Njz]

                    if j==3:
                      Nk = [string.atof(Njx),string.atof(Njy),string.atof(Njz)]

                    print("%s,%s are {:5.16f}, {:5.16f}"%(atom2,atom3)).format(Nj,Nk)
```

Comment: FYI `string.atof` has been deprecated for a while. Use `float()`.

Comment: The problem is that `Nj` hasn't been defined. (Hint: You only define it if `j == 2`).

Comment: @Cyber: "for a while" is a nice expression for "14 years". :-)

Comment: thank you. Now there is a different error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only defining Nj if j==2.  You might have the same error with Nk if j doesn't equal 3 as well.  Try declaring those two values first before your if j==2.

```
Nj = [];
Nk = [];

if j==2:
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for that. However, I now get a different error :(ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

Comment: I used simply        print Nj and print Nk. It now works fine :)

Comment: I assume this error is happening on your print statement?  I believe it is because you are trying to format `Nj` and `Nk`, which are arrays, to float values.  It is actually one of the index's into `Nj` and `Nk` that are floats.